# Axios response return object instead of array

Tags: react-native, axios

I am using axios in react native. Original response in postman looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "Default Category",
    "is_active": true,
    "position": 1,
    "level": 1,
    "product_count": 2,
    "children_data": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "Papers",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 1,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 2,
            "children_data": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "parent_id": 3,
                    "name": "A44",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 1,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 0,
                    "children_data": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "Laptop",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 2,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 1,
            "children_data": []
        }
    ]
}
```

How when i try this   `console.log(typeof categoryResponse.data.children_data);`
I get object. This is causing issue as I am trying to update a state variable in react-native of type array. Even the response object which when printed  `console.log(categoryResponse.data);` looks very odd.

> Object {   "children_data": Array [
>       Object {
>         "children_data": Array [
>           Object {
>             "children_data": Array [],
>             "id": 5,
>             "is_active": true,
>             "level": 3,
>             "name": "A44",
>             "parent_id": 3,
>             "position": 1,
>             "product_count": 0,
>           },
>         ],
>         "id": 3,
>         "is_active": true,
>         "level": 2,
>         "name": "Papers",
>         "parent_id": 2,
>         "position": 1,
>         "product_count": 2,
>       },
>       Object {
>         "children_data": Array [],
>         "id": 6,
>         "is_active": true,
>         "level": 2,
>         "name": "Laptop",
>         "parent_id": 2,
>         "position": 2,
>         "product_count": 1,
>       },   ],   "id": 2,   "is_active": true,   "level": 1,   "name": "Default Category",   "parent_id": 1,   "position": 1,
>   "product_count": 2, }

Please help

Answer (score 1):

In javascript , typeof array is actually an object. In javascript there are only 6 datatypes. Arrays are subsets of objects , so hence `console.log(typeof categoryResponse.data.children_data)` returns object even if its an array.

But you can see when you `console.log(categoryResponse.data)` , you see

```
Object { "children_data": Array [ Object { "children_data": Array [ Object { "children_data": Array [], "id": 5, "is_active": true, "level": 3, "name": "A44", "parent_id": 3, "position": 1, "product_count": 0, }, ], "id": 3, "is_active": true, "level": 2, "name": "Papers", "parent_id": 2, "position": 1, "product_count": 2, }, Object { "children_data": Array [], "id": 6, "is_active": true, "level": 2, "name": "Laptop", "parent_id": 2, "position": 2, "product_count": 1, }, ], "id": 2, "is_active": true, "level": 1, "name": "Default Category", "parent_id": 1, "position": 1,
"product_count": 2, }
```

and here you see "childern_data" as an array right.

```
"children_data": Array [ Object {
```

so basically its an array, dont let typeof confuse you .

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts, ill clear it

Comment: then why is array is still empty?
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
      setCategories(categoryResponse.data.children_data);
      console.log(categories);

Comment: where is it empty? its there right? only third nested ""children_data": []" is empty and thats acording to the postman

Comment: "categoryResponse.data.children_data" this should be array of content..right?
after setting in hook varaible, the hook variable still shows as empty in console.log(categories)

Comment: umm, but just console.log(categoryResponse.data.children_data) , and if its not empty that means ,something wrong with setState code, share it an expo snack link, will check there

Comment: Fixed the problem..Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204530/discussion-between-gaurav-roy-and-saurav).